# scipy.io.wavfile gives "WavFileWarning: chunk not understood" error

Tags: python, macos, numpy, audio, scipy

I'm trying to read a .wav file using scipy. I do this:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

filename = "myWavFile.wav"
print "Processing " + filename

samples = wavfile.read(filename)
```

And I get this ugly error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py:121: WavFileWarning: chunk not understood
  warnings.warn("chunk not understood", WavFileWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fingerFooler.py", line 15, in <module>
    samples = wavfile.read(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 127, in read
    size = struct.unpack(fmt, data)[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

I'm using Python 2.6.6, numpy 1.6.2, and scipy 0.11.0

[Here's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34317751/Shakers.wav) a wav file that causes the problem.

Any thoughts? What's wrong here?

Comment: try `samples = wavfile.read(open(filename, 'r'))`

Comment: Tried it, still got the same error...

Comment: are you sure your .wav file is standard? is it uncompressed or not?

Comment: Have you tried Python's `wave` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know anything about the WAV file format, but digging into the `scipy` code it looks like `scipy` isn't familiar with the chunk that's present towards the end of the file (chunk ID is `bext`, 2753632 bytes in, if that helps). That chunk is declared as 603 bytes long so it reads past it expecting another chunk ID 603 bytes later -- it doesn't find it (runs out of file) and falls over.

Have you tried it on other WAV files successfully? How was this one generated?

Comment: Indeed... It was a problem with the WAV file (even though any audio player could play them). I tried the code with WAVs generated with another program and it worked. 

The problematic wav files were created in... Apple's Logic Pro, with standard settings: 16bit, 44100Hz, Interleaved, no dithering.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used sox to "convert" my wav files to the format they already had. Thereby sox corrected erroneous wav files, while the audio data stayed the same. See http://stefaanlippens.net/audio_conversion_cheat_sheet

Answer (score 29):

The files is no longer available (not surprising after 9 months!), but for future reference the most likely cause is that it had extra metadata which scipy can't parse.

In my case, it was default metadata (copyright, track name etc) which was added by Audacity- you can open the file in Audacity and use File ... Open Metadata Editor to see it.  Then use the 'Clear' button to strip it, and try again.

The [current version of scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/wavfile.py) supports the following RIFF chunks - 'fmt', 'fact', 'data' and 'LIST'.  [The Wikipedia page on RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) has a bit more detail on how a WAV file is structured, for example yours might have included an unsupported-but-popular INFO chunk

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution to this problem is to convert the wav file into other wav file using SoX.

```
$ sox wavfile.wav wavfile2.wav
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and could successfully convert to what it can read.

My original file was from Logic Pro. Then I used [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to read the file.

Comment: The same issue here. I've also exported my wave file from Logic Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error because of (presumably) metadata introduced by Audacity. I exported my wav file from another DAW (Ableton Live), and scipy.io.wavfile loaded it without error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem when exporting from Reaper:
simply deselect "Write BWF ('bext') chunk" in the *Render to File* window.