# How to fix 'Incomplete wav chunk' error when reading wav with scipy

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, scipy

#### My problem

I'm trying to fit a (machine-learning) model that takes in an audiofile (.wav) and predicts the emotion from it (multi-label classification).
I'm trying to read the sample rate and signal from the file, but when calling `read(filename)` from `scipy.io.wavfile`, I'm getting `ValueError: Incomplete wav chunk.`

#### What I've tried

1. I've tried switching from `scipy.read()` to `librosa.read()`.
   They both output the signal and sample rate, but for some reason `librosa` takes exponentially longer time than `scipy`, and is impractical for my task.
2. I've tried `sr, y = scipi.io.wavfile.read(open(filename, 'r'))` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321627/scipy-io-wavfile-gives-wavfilewarning-chunk-not-understood-error#comment19901173_14321627), to no avail.
3. I've tried looking into my files and checking what might cause it:
   Out of all 2084 wav files, 1057 were good (=scipy managed to read them), and 
   1027 were bad (=raised the error).
   I couldn't seem to find any thing pointing as to what makes a file pass or fail, but nonetheless it's a weird result, as all files are taken from the same dataset from the same [origin](https://zenodo.org/record/1188976#.XQn3DogzZEZ).
4. I've heard people saying I could just re-export the files as wav using some software, and it should work.
   I didn't try this because a) I don't have any audio-processing software and it seems like an overkill, and b) I want to understand the actual problem rather than put a bandaid on it.

#### Minimal, reproducible example

Assume `filenames` is a subset of all my audio files, containing [fn_good](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7f066e7b671c165074f736746c3e010320190619114637/cf26fa) and [fn_bad](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ccea2cdc20ff7df3518ca8b9212bf12020190619114543/13cf12), where `fn_good` is an actual file that gets processed, and `fn_bad` is an actual file that raises an error.

```py
def extract_features(filenames):
    for fn in filenames:
        sr, y = scipy.io.wavfile.read(fn)
        print('Signal is: ', y)
        print('Sample rate is: ', sr)
```

#### Additional info

Using VLC, it seems that the codecs are supported by `scipy.io.wavfile`, but in either case, both files have the same codec, so it's weird they don't have the same effect... 
Codec of the GOOD file:
[image]

Codec of the BAD file:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `scipy.io.wavfile` can't read the file--there might be an invalid chunk in there that other readers simply ignore.  Note that even when I read a "good" file with `scipy.io.wavfile`, a warning (`WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.`) is generated:

```
In [22]: rate, data = wavfile.read('fearful_song_strong_dogs_act10_f_1.wav')                              
/Users/warren/mc37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py:273: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)
```

I can read `'fearful_song_strong_dogs_act06_f_0.wav'` using [`wavio`](https://pypi.org/project/wavio/) (source code on github: [`wavio`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio)), a package I created that wraps Python's standard `wave` library with functions that understand NumPy arrays:

```
In [13]: import wavio                                                                                     

In [14]: wav = wavio.read('fearful_song_strong_dogs_act06_f_0.wav')                                       

In [15]: wav                                                                                              
Out[15]: Wav(data.shape=(198598, 1), data.dtype=int16, rate=48000, sampwidth=2)

In [16]: plot(np.arange(wav.data.shape[0])/wav.rate, wav.data[:,0])                                       
Out[16]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x117cd9390>]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! As you recommended, I tried using ```wavio``` and it seems to work great.  
(Not accepting this as an answer as I still want to know why scipy is acting that way...)

Comment: No problem.  If you have a moment, you could create an issue on the scipy github page (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues; click the green "New issue" button).  Explain the problem, and include links to this stackoverflow question and to the examples of "good" and "bad" wav files.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by changing this number **"4" to "1"**  in the file wavefile.py file,
in this condition of the code:
-   **len(chunk_id) < 1**

```
   if not chunk_id:
            raise ValueError("Unexpected end of file.")
        elif len(chunk_id) < 1:
            raise ValueError("Incomplete wav chunk.")
```

but it was by just intuition and good luck, now i wonder why this works and what are the possible reasons?
[image]